# "Unresolved function or method" error using a nodeJs package

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, jshint

Intellij is giving me a jshint warning when using a method of a node package.

> Unresolved function or method channel

The offending code looks like this.

```
var channel = require('pubsub').channel('some-channel-name');
```

The package looks like this.

```
var g = typeof window === 'undefined' ? global : window;
module.exports = g.__PUBSUB || (g.__PUBSUB = require('./lib/pubsub'));
```

Im guessing jshint is confused by the conditional, other packages don't have this issue. How do I describe the object being exported for jshint so this warning will go away.

Comment: did you install the package via npm? If not, try stating the relative path to the package in your require function

Comment: the package pubsub is published in node_modules. if I `module.exports = {channel:function () {}}` the warning goes away.

Comment: and `module.exports = require('./lib/pubsub');` also solves it